# Android save image to sqlite database on background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, image, sqlite

OK, I know there are (potential) downsides to saving an image to SQLite, but that is how I'm doing things.

That said, I'm currently saving an image to the app sqlite db using this:

```
private void setValuesAndSave() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if (userAvatarChanged==true){
        byte[] avatarData = ImageFileHelper.convertDrawableToByteArray(avatarView.getDrawable());
        values.put(UserDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USER_AVATAR, avatarData);  
    }
    values.put(UserDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME, firstname.getText().toString());
    values.put(UserDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USER_LAST_NAME, lastname.getText().toString());


    int count = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(UserProvider.CONTENT_URI, ROWID), values, null, null);
    if (count!=1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to update " + ROWID);
    }   
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Which totally works. BUT -- there is a slight but noticeable delay when the "Save" button is tapped, and when the UI is free again. I'm pretty new to android and java so I'm not totally sure how to complete this save without locking the UI thread... If anyone is willing I'd really appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I decided to place things in a Runnable and run on a new Thread. I was going to post code here but too many characters... I'm still open to other ideas if anyone would like to suggest.

Comment: I suggest you learn about AsyncTask. This class was created for just these kinds of situations.

Comment: how about using an asynctask?